# How to import data from a Google Sheets table to BigQuery?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I'm taking this Google Data Analytics Certification Course on Cousera and I'm having some trouble learning SQL. I was wondering how I would import data from a Google Sheets table to BigQuery?

I tried following this article: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Importing-Google-Sheets-into-a-BigQuery-Table/m-p/604595

But then I get an error message on BigQuery saying my table doesn't have a schema and I'm unsure how to create a schema for my table.